# Electron browserwindow blocking x-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, electron, cross-domain

I am trying to embed an iframe into my electron application and cannot get passed the "Only secure origins are allowed" errors.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GD0M.png)

Using an express server to host a local HTML file that has a Google recaptcha iframe causes this error ONLY inside of the browserwindow of electron. When connecting to the express server through chrome, I don't have the issue.

```
expressApp = express()
expressApp.set('port', parseInt(eSettings.getSync('port')));
expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

expressApp.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./captcha.html', {root: __dirname});
    capWin.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:""}, function () {});
})

var server = expressApp.listen(expressApp.get('port'));

win.webContents.session.setProxy({
  proxyRules: `http://127.0.0.1:${parseInt(eSettings.getSync('port'))}`
}, function (r) {
    capWin.loadURL(eSettings.getSync('host'));
});
```

I have tried disabling web security, adding  tags to the html, and adding a line to my hosts file and nothing has worked.

So why am I getting this issue in electron and is there a way around it?

Comment: Where are you declaring `win` and `capWin`?

Comment: Also, why are you parsing an Integer from a String then converting it back to a String?

Comment: `var win, settingsWin, capWin, loginWindow;`
`win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 650,
            height: 650,
            minWidth: 650,
            minHeight: 650,
            resizable: true,
            maxWidth: 650,
            maxHeight: 650,
            fullscreenable: false,
            frame: true,
            show: true,
            webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
        })`

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] reproducing the issue. You don't show how you open the windows, what you declare or how you declare it. There is not enough information here to even hazard a guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: Also, `resizable: true`, `frame: true`, and `show: true` are the defaults, so declaring them again is unnecessary.